# Expand width of an flexbox child element to 100% if the element has to wrap - jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

Every time I have to make a flexbox responsive, I have to use the @media screen.

Is there a smarter way of doing it with jQuery or JavaScript, where if an element has wrapped (due to lowering the screen size, viewing from mobile, etc.), it becomes `width: 100%` and has no left or right margin?

On desktop view, I have a grid layout using a flexbox and had assigned a smaller width to the child divs and some margin between them:

```
<div class="flexbox">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

```
.flexbox {
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:100%:
}

.flexbox div {
  width:30%;
  min-width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:green;
}

.flexbox div:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left:5%;
}
```

Comment: with this configuration your elements will never wrap

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected it